# Kappa condition number in R

Tags: r, matrix, condition-number

I have read that the `kappa` function in R does not always explicitly calculate the condition number of a matrix, but rather, estimates the 2 norm of a matrix or a QR decomposition (see [here](https://rdrr.io/r/base/kappa.html)). I was just wondering if anyone knows what the approximation used here is and has any idea where I can read more about the math of the underlying algorithm behind `kappa`?

Update: As user `yarnabrina` has pointed out, the functions in the R source code I am particularly interested in are `.kappa_tri` and `kappa.qr`. Thanks again to `yarnabrina` and also any future answers!

Comment: Yeah but it was the best anyone did and the bounty would have expired! Cheers again.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of `kappa`, you can use `exact = TRUE`, and it'll use SVD for the exact calculation.

> For kappa(), if exact = FALSE (the default) the 2-norm condition number is estimated by a cheap approximation. However, the exact calculation (via svd) is also likely to be quick enough.

For details of the method, you can check the source code, available at [here](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/base/R/kappa.R). Here's a part from that:

```
kappa.default <- function(z, exact = FALSE,
                          norm = NULL, method = c("qr", "direct"), ...)
{
    method <- match.arg(method)
    z <- as.matrix(z)
    norm <- if(!is.null(norm)) match.arg(norm, c("2", "1","O", "I")) else "2"
    if(exact && norm == "2") {
        s <- svd(z, nu = 0, nv = 0)$d
        max(s)/min(s[s > 0])
    }
    else { ## exact = FALSE or norm in "1", "O", "I"
    if(exact)
        warning(gettextf("norm '%s' currently always uses exact = FALSE",
                 norm))
        d <- dim(z)
        if(method == "qr" || d[1L] != d[2L])
        kappa.qr(qr(if(d[1L] < d[2L]) t(z) else z),
             exact = FALSE, norm = norm, ...)
        else .kappa_tri(z, exact = FALSE, norm = norm, ...)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah okay I see thank you... apologies I was really hoping to understand the approximations `kappa_qr` and `kappa_tri`? I guess the only way to see is to look at the source code? I find it hard to tell what is going on here as they call to fortran in this code it seems.

Comment: @JDoe2 I don't know Fortran myself, sorry. What I understand from the link is that `kappa.qr` calls `.kappa_tri`, and hence I don't follow why do you want to find their difference.

Comment: No worries, thank you for your time though! Do you know what `.kappa_tri` does though? I only wish to know what the methods are doing - at the moment I'm not really sure on either! Thanks again though!